# dynamically created python object doesn't have __new__ attribute

Tags: python, serialization, reflection

I'm writing a simple XML serializer and caught a strange problem. If an object being serialized inherited from *object* explicitly everything works fine - I can serialize and deserialize it.

But if I don't specify *object* explicitly, it fails to deserialize despite the fact *object* is in mro:

i.e.

```
class ScanResults(object):
```

works fine, but

```
class ScanResults:
```

doesn't work

```
MRO :[<class 'aplib.scanresults.ScanResults'>, <class 'aplib.pyxmlser.pyxmlser'>, <type 'object'>]

Traceback (most recent call last):
... 
   classinst = classobj.__new__(classobj, None, None)

AttributeError: class AccessPoint has no attribute '__new__'
```

Any ideas is much appreciated.

Comment: You must by on Python 2.x. Look up new-style classes. [Here's](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Old-style classes (those not derived from `object`) don't have `__new__()`.

Comment: Sure, but I beleive that for old style classes _object_ shouldn't appear in inheritance chain

Comment: Where's that MRO coming from? Old-style classes don't have `__mro__` either.

Comment: type(<instance>).mro()

Comment: Is there a way to instantiate old-style class?

Comment: Yes, `object` does appear in the inheritance chain for new-style instances. That's because all old-style instances are instances of a single type, dubbed `instance`, which inherits from `object`. In other words `instance` (what you get when you instantiate an old-style class) is a new-style class! But since old-style classes are not actually an instance of the class they were instantiated from, their MRO has nothing to do with the MRO of the original class.

Comment: For the first "new-style" in my preceding comment, read "old-style." Oops.

Comment: Just as a side-note: `isinstance()` actually does work seem to work correctly for instances of old style classes, so both `isinstance(foo, types.InstanceType)` as well as `ininstance(foo, Foo)` evaluate to `True` (where `foo` is an instance of the old style class `Foo`).

Answer (score 0):

One way to test if an instance is an old-style clase (which fail) is to use

```
type(my_instance) is types.InstanceType
```

which will evaluate to `True` for old-style classes.

Comment: Thanks! It's very close to what I'd looked for.

Comment: You're supposed to be using `isinstance(obj, class)` in Python; it also works in this case: `isistance(my_instance, types.InstanceType)`.

Comment: @ErikAllik I concede that `isinstance`'ll work in this case but it's less *obvious* that it'll work for multiple inheritance. The advantage of `isinstance` is ducktyping, which isn't relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

some input about why use `__new()__` and how to check in a more clean way for the creation of a new instance:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-April/061426.html

tips for overwritting the `__new()__` method [to be found here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__).